# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class...on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Guys I'm having a strange error and it's driving me crazy please help me.
Here is the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.zapps.mars/net.zapps.mars.UserPreferencesActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/net.zapps.mars-ttDnBZn3oo8rm4zh7vudMQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/net.zapps.mars-ttDnBZn3oo8rm4zh7vudMQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/net.zapps.mars-ttDnBZn3oo8rm4zh7vudMQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:801)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:874)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at net.zapps.mars.UserPreferencesActivity.onCreate(UserPreferencesActivity.java:64)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7372)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3147)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Here is my layout

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/upDP"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_man"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I've read the error (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class ) is related to some Multidex thing. But I am not using that. Please help me.

I've done everything from cleaning the project. Invalidating the cache. Deleting build folder etc. Nothing is working.

Followed the exact procedure here: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView
Library works in one of my old apps but not in this app

Comment: The error states that it cannot find the class you're using at the beginning of your code segment: `de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView`. Probably because of an incorrectly imported module.

Comment: I did exactly what's described here: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

In of my old apps it was working but in my new app it's not

Comment: Like I said the import of the module is probably not correct, have you checked the depenencies, maybe something is misspelled? There also could be a version problem, have you updated something recently?

Comment: I have made a new project...import the module same way as before and it's working fine there but not in this project. Checked many times here everything is as required.

One thing I noticed is that even I've not enabled multidex but still I'm getting multiple dex files in this project while other projects where library is working fine has only one dex file. Is something related?

Comment: Probably, but I'm no expert on this. Maybe the author of that module knows more.